# Why are Hindu beliefs and facts called mythological?

Tags: belief, rama, consciousness

Why does every time anybody referring to a Hindu cultural thing says it's Hindu **mythology**?

Because "**mythology**" means:

> **Mythology** is a collection of myths, especially one belonging to a particular sacred, religious or cultural tradition of a group of people. Myths are a collection of stories told to explain nature, history, and customs–or the study of such myths.

**Hindu culture** is based on strong scientific evidence. Although people call Lord **Rama** as mythological character, [recent scientific studies](http://www.stephen-knapp.com/lord_rama_fact_or_fiction.htm) proved the existence of Lord Rama and his vanaras.

As all of this is a scientific fact that we don't tell others, so please don't refer to Hinduism as 'mythological' in any manner.

Comment: With time History becomes legend and legend becomes Mythology. See this [meta Answer](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/293/3500).

Comment: @AnilKumar this should not happen. are we not responsible for that.? we should change it.

Comment: You should see first who labels our history as mythology.The answer lies within that answer.

Comment: We have archaeological evidences for both Ramayana and Mahabharatha too.So they are our history.

Comment: @Rickross but why they are still referred as Mythological? SOme days back i had a argument with a person because he was calling Ashoka as mythological character.

Comment: Because we are lazy .Changes don't occur that fast in our country.Text books and allied stuffs needs a complete revision.Even the so called aryan invasion theory which is still taught in schools has been proved to be a fake one.And you should not argue with ignorant fools.infact  you cant convince them no matter what you do.

Comment: More importantly the saints who wrote Ramayana and Mahabharatha never said that they are writing stories.And saints don't lie.This is a good enough logic for  convincing the believers.For the non believers, however , no reasons suffice.However we have archaeological evidences which seems powerful enough to silence the critics.